# Can I use an NFC tag to launch iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I use an NFC tag to do more than just launch my iPhone application.

Being a bit more specific: I would like to know whether there's a iOS application that can automatically launch when comes near to NFC tags.

Comment: What NFC solution have you found?

Comment: Provided there is an NFC interface to iOS you would essentially need to rely on URL handlers supported by specific apps.

Answer (score 4):

iOS now has `CoreNFC` allowing apps to read NFC tags using an iPhone 7 or newer. However, you can't make Springboard load your app based on one. You could, in theory, have another app that used an NFC tag to "boot" apps, but you'd never get it approved for the App Store.

Historical answer: Given that no shipping iPhone has an NFC sensor, no.

Answer (score -1):

Today iPhone can recognize NFC tags with web site addresses recorded on them.
When you swipe the tag with a website address record, it pops up with a message and asks if u want to go to the web site.
You can create a website with triggers; it can send a message, show information, and more.
There is a really useful app on iPhone called shortcuts, with this you can create a lot of automation.